# Cannot pinch zoom if both fingers touch screen simultaneously

Tags: java, android, gesture, pinchzoom

I have implemented zoom on my custom made view which draws a grid onto a canvas, but the zooming won't work if I put both fingers on the screen simultaneously. I have to first put one, then the other.

I followed [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html) blog post by Adam Powell to implement zoom, and made this custom view:

```
public class ZoomView extends View{

    private float width;    
    private float height;   

    Paint lineColor; 
    Paint bgColor;

    private float mScaleFactor;
    private ScaleGestureDetector scaleDetector;

    public CanvasView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

        lineColor = new Paint();
        lineColor.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        bgColor = new Paint();
        bgColor.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));

        mScaleFactor = 1;
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh){
        width = w/9;
        height = h/9;
        super.onSizeChanged(w,h,oldw,oldh);
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.save();
        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);     //for zooming

        for(int i=0; i <= 9; i++){
            canvas.drawLine(0,i*height, 9*width,i*height,lineColor);
            canvas.drawLine(i*width, 0, i*width, 9*height, lineColor);
        }

        canvas.restore();
    }

    @Override 
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){

        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
        setMeasuredDimension(800, 1000);
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

            // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
            mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 5.0f));

            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    }   
}
```

So why is the zooming behaving this way?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This may look like a silly question, but does the multi touch behavior work on other apps (Maps for example) at this device?
I've tested your code (with minor changes, see below) on an LG Optimus Black, Android 4.0.3, and it worked, both fingers simultaneously.

```
package com.example.teste;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;

public class ZoomView extends View {

private float width;
private float height;

Paint lineColor;
Paint bgColor;

private float mScaleFactor;
private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

public ZoomView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

    lineColor = new Paint();
    lineColor.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.ics_blue_bright));
    bgColor = new Paint();
    bgColor.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));

    mScaleFactor = 1;
    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    width = w / 9;
    height = h / 9;
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.save();
    canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor); // for zooming

    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
        canvas.drawLine(0, i * height, 9 * width, i * height, lineColor);
        canvas.drawLine(i * width, 0, i * width, 9 * height, lineColor);
    }

    canvas.restore();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

    mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    setMeasuredDimension(800, 1000);
}

private class ScaleListener extends
        ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

        // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
        mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 5.0f));

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Yes, other apps work fine with zoom. I'm using a motorola droid HD ... I think I'll test it on another phone I have now that you mention it. Also, which changes did you make to the code? I didn't notice any on first glance

Comment: I've changed
`private ScaleGestureDetector scaleDetector;

public CanvasView(Context context) {`

to

`private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

public ZoomView(Context context) {`

Comment: Hey Luiza. I was able to get this working on another phone, so I'm going to do a factory reset on my droid and see if that fixes this (it is having other problems anyway).